# Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

When a user clicks on a link, I want to populate a modal dialog and show it. So I am populating this model dialog with the response of a GET method, using AJAX, like the following:

HTML:

```
<a data-rec="@Model.rec" data-seg="@Model.seg" data-det="@Model.seg" class="btn btn-default checkRulesLink">Check Rules</a>
<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#dialog-rules").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  title: "Details",
  buttons: {
    Close: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});

$(".checkRulesLink").click(function(e) {
  $("#dialog-rules").html("");
  e.preventDefault();
  var rec = $(this).data('rec');
  var seg = $(this).data('seg');
  var det = $(this).data('det');
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Booking/CheckRules?rec=" + rec + "&seg=" + seg + "&det=" + det,
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      $("#dialog-rules").html(result);
      $("#dialog-rules").dialog("open");
    }
  });
});
```

The AJAX call works fine, but whenever I click on the link, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
    at Function.error (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:253)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (VM33 jquery-ui.js:246)
    at Function.each (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:370)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:137)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as dialog] (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:236:10)
    at Object.success (Flights:18216)
    at fire (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
    at done (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)
error @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:253
(anonymous) @ VM33 jquery-ui.js:246
each @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:370
each @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:137
$.fn.(anonymous function) @ VM33 jquery-ui.js:236
success @ Flights:18216
fire @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
fireWith @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
done @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9840
callback @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10311
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10254
ajax @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
(anonymous) @ Flights:18211
dispatch @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878
2VM95:46 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function
    at Object.swing (eval at <anonymous> (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:349), <anonymous>:46:42)
    at init.run (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7402)
    at tick (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7747)
    at jQuery.fx.tick (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8069)
swing @ VM95:46
run @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7402
tick @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7747
jQuery.fx.tick @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8069
setInterval (async)
jQuery.fx.start @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8093
jQuery.fx.timer @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8083
Animation @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7823
doAnimation @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7926
dequeue @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4157
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4201
each @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:370
each @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:137
queue @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4194
animate @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7937
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8053
(anonymous) @ VM83:24
fire @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
add @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3291
jQuery.fn.ready @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3542
(anonymous) @ VM83:1
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:349
globalEval @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:350
text script @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10372
ajaxConvert @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9332
done @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9789
callback @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10311
send @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10321
ajax @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
jQuery._evalUrl @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9902
domManip @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6086
append @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6269
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6375
access @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4399
html @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6338
success @ Flights:18215
fire @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
fireWith @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
done @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9840
callback @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10311
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10254
ajax @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
(anonymous) @ Flights:18211
dispatch @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878
js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:95 You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
Hg @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:95
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:158
google.maps.Load @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:18
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:158
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:159
373VM95:46 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function
    at Object.swing (eval at <anonymous> (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:349), <anonymous>:46:42)
    at init.run (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7402)
    at tick (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7747)
    at jQuery.fx.tick (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8069)
swing @ VM95:46
run @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7402
tick @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7747
jQuery.fx.tick @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8069
setInterval (async)
jQuery.fx.start @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8093
jQuery.fx.timer @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8083
Animation @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7823
doAnimation @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7926
dequeue @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4157
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4201
each @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:370
each @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:137
queue @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4194
animate @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7937
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8053
(anonymous) @ VM83:24
fire @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
add @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3291
jQuery.fn.ready @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3542
(anonymous) @ VM83:1
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:349
globalEval @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:350
text script @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10372
ajaxConvert @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9332
done @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9789
callback @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10311
send @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10321
ajax @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
jQuery._evalUrl @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9902
domManip @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6086
append @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6269
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6375
access @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4399
html @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6338
success @ Flights:18215
fire @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
fireWith @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
done @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9840
callback @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10311
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10254
ajax @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
(anonymous) @ Flights:18211
dispatch @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878
maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?target=api&ev=api_alreadyloaded&client=&key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg&cad=src:apiv3,token:4u7gju54e3,ts:nhesob:1 GET http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?target=api&ev=api_alreadyloaded&client=&key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg&cad=src:apiv3,token:4u7gju54e3,ts:nhesob 0 ()
Image (async)
LY.b @ stats.js:5
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:158
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:63
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:60
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:63
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:135
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:60
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:135
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:60
(anonymous) @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:135
Rd @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:63
Qd.va @ js?key=AIzaSyASHcSQGj-zxu3xPF5e07MFU4L_jxxBXcg:135
(anonymous) @ util.js:1
2334VM95:46 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function
    at Object.swing (eval at <anonymous> (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:349), <anonymous>:46:42)
    at init.run (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7402)
    at tick (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7747)
    at jQuery.fx.tick (VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8069)
swing @ VM95:46
run @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7402
tick @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7747
jQuery.fx.tick @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8069
setInterval (async)
jQuery.fx.start @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8093
jQuery.fx.timer @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8083
Animation @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7823
doAnimation @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7926
dequeue @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4157
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4201
each @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:370
each @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:137
queue @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4194
animate @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:7937
jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:8053
(anonymous) @ VM83:24
fire @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
add @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3291
jQuery.fn.ready @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3542
(anonymous) @ VM83:1
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:349
globalEval @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:350
text script @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10372
ajaxConvert @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9332
done @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9789
callback @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10311
send @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10321
ajax @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
jQuery._evalUrl @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9902
domManip @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6086
append @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6269
(anonymous) @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6375
access @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4399
html @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:6338
success @ Flights:18215
fire @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3232
fireWith @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:3362
done @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9840
callback @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10311
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:10254
ajax @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:9738
(anonymous) @ Flights:18211
dispatch @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226
elemData.handle @ VM32 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code seems to be working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/2wLs0h6x/5/, you need to provide more info like what are the libraries imported in your page. the actual error is `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function`

Comment: Your stack trace snippet points out that your animation call `jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function` is throwing an error, this results in a cascading error which ends at `dialog`.

Check your code where the animation is happening, you haven't included a full enough example here so I don't think there's anything more to add.

Example of your code above working fine in isolation: https://codepen.io/nazimjamil/pen/GBxROJ

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue by trying out the suggested answers and/or by arriving to other solution?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this error occurs *(as the error itself states)*, is that you try to call a method **before** the [**Dialog Widget**](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog) is initialized:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog **prior to initialization**; attempted to call method 'open' ...

**In the snippet below the error is demonstrated** (*In order to see the actual error, open the browser's developer console.*):

```js
function mockAjax(object) {
  console.log('Loaded:', object.url);
  object.success('Data as result from AJAX');
}

$(function() {  
  $(".checkRulesLink").click(function(e) {
    $("#dialog-rules").html("");
    e.preventDefault();
    var rec = $(this).data('rec');
    var seg = $(this).data('seg');
    var det = $(this).data('det');
    mockAjax({
      url: "/Booking/CheckRules?rec=" + rec + "&seg=" + seg + "&det=" + det,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $("#dialog-rules").html(result);
        $("#dialog-rules").dialog("open");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a data-rec="@Model.rec" data-seg="@Model.seg" data-det="@Model.seg" class="btn btn-default checkRulesLink">Check Rules</a>
<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog"></div>
```

### Note:

For the sake of demonstration, the AJAX call is mocked using this `function`:

```
function mockAjax(object) {
  console.log('Loaded:', object.url);
  object.success('Data as result from AJAX');
}
```

---

## The possible causes of this error:

### - Code structure:

Because of the actual structure of your **full codebase**, it is possible that the `$.ajax({...});` call runs before the actual initialization of the [**Dialog Widget**](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog), e.g.:

- incorrect order of `<script>` elements
- `<script>` elements with `defer`/`async` attributes loading at different times
- unnoticed, incorrect VCS merges
- minification
- typos in general

**Make sure, that:**

- all the necessary `<link/>` and `<script>` resources are placed properly and loaded without errors
- your code is wrapped in [**`$(function() { ... });`**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) to prevent the code running before the **DOM** is loaded
- check, whether the **Dialog Widget** is initialized on the element, by using:

  ```
  if ($("#dialog-rules").dialog && !$("#dialog-rules").dialog("instance")) {
    console.log("The dialog widget is not initialized on this element");
  }
  ```

And either initialize your **Dialog Widget** in the `if` statement:

```
var element = $("#dialog-rules");

if (element.dialog && !element.dialog("instance")) {
  element.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Details",
    buttons: {
      Close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Or better, **separate the initialization** in its own `function` and call it, when it's needed:

```
function initDialog(element) {
  if (element.dialog && !element.dialog("instance")) {
    element.dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      title: "Details",
      buttons: {
        Close: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

// ... later in your code ...
initDialog($("#dialog-rules"))
// ...
```

#### Example:

```js
function mockAjax(object) {
  console.log('Loaded:', object.url);
  object.success('Data as result from AJAX');
}

function initDialog(element) {
  if (element.dialog && !element.dialog("instance")) {
    console.log("The dialog is not initialized, initialize now");    
    element.dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      title: "Details",
      buttons: {
        Close: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

$(function() {
  $(".checkRulesLink").click(function(e) {
    $("#dialog-rules").html("");
    e.preventDefault();
    var rec = $(this).data('rec');
    var seg = $(this).data('seg');
    var det = $(this).data('det');
    mockAjax({
      url: "/Booking/CheckRules?rec=" + rec + "&seg=" + seg + "&det=" + det,
      success: function(result) {
        var element = $("#dialog-rules");        
        
        console.log(result);
        initDialog(element);
        element.html(result);
        element.dialog("open");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a data-rec="@Model.rec" data-seg="@Model.seg" data-det="@Model.seg" class="btn btn-default checkRulesLink">Check Rules</a>
<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog"></div>
```

[**More on the `instance()` method**](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-instance)

---

### - The element was replaced:

In case the `#dialog-rules` element was replaced, e.g.:

```
// ... somewhere/for some reason the element is replaced ...
$("#dialog-rules").remove(); // or .replaceWith(), or .html() on the parent element
$("body").append('<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog"></div>');
// ...
```

The **Dialog Widget** has to be **reinitialized** on the new, but *seemingly old* element:

#### Example without reinitialization (will throw the error):

```js
function mockAjax(object) {
  console.log('Loaded:', object.url);
  object.success('Data as result from AJAX');
}

$(function() {
  // The dialog widget is properly initialized on the element
  $("#dialog-rules").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Details",
    buttons: {
      Close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
      }
    }
  });
  
  // somewhere/for some reason the element is replaced ...
  $("#dialog-rules").remove();
  $("body").append('<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog"></div>');
  // ...

  $(".checkRulesLink").click(function(e) {
    $("#dialog-rules").html("");
    e.preventDefault();
    var rec = $(this).data('rec');
    var seg = $(this).data('seg');
    var det = $(this).data('det');
    mockAjax({
      url: "/Booking/CheckRules?rec=" + rec + "&seg=" + seg + "&det=" + det,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $("#dialog-rules").html(result);
        $("#dialog-rules").dialog("open");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a data-rec="@Model.rec" data-seg="@Model.seg" data-det="@Model.seg" class="btn btn-default checkRulesLink">Check Rules</a>
<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog"></div>
```

#### Example with reinitialization (no error):

```js
function mockAjax(object) {
  console.log('Loaded:', object.url);
  object.success('Data as result from AJAX');
}

function initWidget(element) {
  // reinitialize only, when needed
  if (element.dialog && !element.dialog("instance")) {
    element.dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      title: "Details",
      buttons: {
        Close: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

$(function() {
  // The dialog widget is properly initialized on the element
  initWidget($("#dialog-rules"));
  
  // somewhere/for some reason the element is replaced ...
  $("#dialog-rules").remove();
  $("body").append('<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog"></div>');
  // ...

  $(".checkRulesLink").click(function(e) {
    $("#dialog-rules").html("");
    e.preventDefault();
    var rec = $(this).data('rec');
    var seg = $(this).data('seg');
    var det = $(this).data('det');
    mockAjax({
      url: "/Booking/CheckRules?rec=" + rec + "&seg=" + seg + "&det=" + det,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        initWidget($("#dialog-rules"))
        $("#dialog-rules").html(result);
        $("#dialog-rules").dialog("open");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a data-rec="@Model.rec" data-seg="@Model.seg" data-det="@Model.seg" class="btn btn-default checkRulesLink">Check Rules</a>
<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog"></div>
```

### - The widget was destroyed:

If the widget was destroyed using `.dialog("destroy")`, e.g.:

```
// ... somewhere/for some reason the dialog widget is destroyed ...
$("#dialog-rules").dialog("destroy");
// ...
```

The element `#dialog-rules` is returned its pre-init state. In order to use the **Dialog Widget** again, its reinitialization is needed:

#### Example with reinitialization:

```js
function mockAjax(object) {
  console.log('Loaded:', object.url);
  object.success('Data as result from AJAX');
}

function initWidget(element) {
  // reinitialize only, when needed
  if (element.dialog && !element.dialog("instance")) {
    element.dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      title: "Details",
      buttons: {
        Close: function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

$(function() {
  // The dialog widget is properly initialized on the element
  initWidget($("#dialog-rules"));
  
  // somewhere/for some reason the dialog widget is destroyed ...
  $("#dialog-rules").dialog('destroy');
  // ...

  $(".checkRulesLink").click(function(e) {
    $("#dialog-rules").html("");
    e.preventDefault();
    var rec = $(this).data('rec');
    var seg = $(this).data('seg');
    var det = $(this).data('det');
    mockAjax({
      url: "/Booking/CheckRules?rec=" + rec + "&seg=" + seg + "&det=" + det,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        initWidget($("#dialog-rules"))
        $("#dialog-rules").html(result);
        $("#dialog-rules").dialog("open");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<a data-rec="@Model.rec" data-seg="@Model.seg" data-det="@Model.seg" class="btn btn-default checkRulesLink">Check Rules</a>
<div id="dialog-rules" title="Rules" class="dialog"></div>
```

[**More on the `destroy()` method**](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-destroy)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that jQuery probably does a lot of wrapping and inserts its own meta-data to construct the "dialog" object.

Judging by the sample code from jQuery UI, I'd just use the return value of the `dialog()` jQuery function like so:

```
    var dialog = $("#dialog-rules").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Details",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $(".checkRulesLink").click(function (e) {
        $("#dialog-rules").html("");
        e.preventDefault();
        var rec = $(this).data('rec');
        var seg = $(this).data('seg');
        var det = $(this).data('det');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Booking/CheckRules?rec=" + rec + "&seg=" + seg + "&det=" + det,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $("#dialog-rules").html(result);
                dialog.dialog("open");
            }
        });

    });
```

Notice how when calling `$("#dialog-rules").dialog();` I'm saving the return value to operate on later. In the callback from the ajax request, instead of using the `$("#dialog-rules").dialog("open");` you would use `dialog.dialog("open");`. Not really sure if there is a way to recreate that object later if you lose the reference, but the demos up on jQuery UI follow this method.

Also, as a word of warning, on the `$("#dialog-rules).html();` calls, be careful to edit the actual contents of the dialog. It is possible that jQuery may have wrapped the content section as well. I would check in the DOM explorer how jQuery generates the dialog.